# Access basket/shipping address in django oscar pricing strategy

Tags: django, django-oscar

What would be the best practice to get the shipping address in a pricing strategy? Based on the country selected, I would like to apply tax, or not.

I have an instance of `CheckoutSessionData` in my `Selector`, and the `Selector` inherits from `CheckoutSessionMixin`. But, `CheckoutSessionMixin` needs a basket for many operations, especially for getting a shipping address. And, the `BasketMiddleware` gets it's strategy first, and only then sets the basket on the current request.

So, how to get the shipping address, before? Any best practices?

oscar version is 1.6.3

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is addressed in this part of the documentation - [how to address US taxes](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/how_to_handle_us_taxes.html). You basically need to:

1. Use a `DeferredTax` strategy that returns prices without taxes applied.
2. Override and adjust the checkout views to apply taxes once they are known:

   ```
   def build_submission(self, **kwargs):
      submission = super().build_submission(**kwargs)

       if submission['shipping_address'] and submission['shipping_method']:
           tax.apply_to(submission)

           # Recalculate order total to ensure we have a tax-inclusive total
           submission['order_total'] = self.get_order_totals(
               submission['basket'],
               submission['shipping_charge'])

       return submission
   ```

Where `tax.apply_to` is a function that you define, that determines the appropriate tax for the country of delivery (there's an example in the documentation).

Comment: this is for checkout only, right? I wanted an overall solution, even on product detail pages. I've added my current solution in another answer...not sure if there are any drawbacks (offline processing, not providing a request, for example...)

Comment: I can't see any issues with your approach, other than that the user has to have started checkout and provided their address for it to work (i.e., it's not that far off from doing it at checkout only). I would still use the logic that I've linked to above to make sure the strategy is properly set/reset before the order is created.

Comment: yes. that's true for the current solution. Planned is a further enhanced version, using maxminds geoip, for presenting the user it's "estimated" price and shipping costs, before even providing an address. thanks for feedback!

Answer (score 1):

for now, I'm using this solution, enabling me to apply tax or not throughout my complete site, where `SwissStrategy` includes taxes, and `InternationalStrategy` not. Glad for any feedback.

```
class Selector(CheckoutSessionMixin):
    """
    Responsible for returning the appropriate strategy class for a given
    user/session.

    This can be called in three ways:

    #) Passing a request and user.  This is for determining
       prices/availability for a normal user browsing the site.

    #) Passing just the user.  This is for offline processes that don't
       have a request instance but do know which user to determine prices for.

    #) Passing nothing.  This is for offline processes that don't
       correspond to a specific user.  Eg, determining a price to store in
       a search index.

    """

    def strategy(self, request=None, user=None, **kwargs):

        # TODO: if request, decide based on location/geoip,
        # if to use swiss or international strategy
        country_id = request.session.get(
            'checkout_data', {}).get('shipping', {}).get('new_address_fields', {}).get('country_id', None)
        try:
            country = Country.objects.get(iso_3166_1_a2=country_id)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            country = None
        if not country or country.iso_3166_1_a2 == 'CH':
            return SwissStrategy(request)
        else:
            return InternationalStrategy(request)
```